# populate one dropdown base on another dropdown using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

I have a dropdown which gets the information from a query using mysqli_query()
now, once selecting a choice from the first dropdown I want the second dropdown to be filled with data from a difference query.

This is my code

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.country').on('change', function() {
    // Code to add country information in url
    location.href = location.href.split('?')[0]
        + ['?country', $(this).val()].join('=');
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP First dropdown:

```
<?php
    $countries = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select source from nhws.masterkey group by source;");
    echo "<select name='country' style=width:200px>"; 
    echo "<option size =30 ></option>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($countries)){        
        echo "<option value='".$row['source']."'>".$row['source']."</option>"; 
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

PHP Second dropdown:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['country'])) {
   $country = $_GET['country'];
   echo $country;
   $variables = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select variable from nhws.num_all_{$country} group by variable;");
   echo "<select name='variable' style=width:200px>"; 
   echo "<option size =30 ></option>";
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($variables)) {        
     echo "<option value='".$row['variable']."'>".$row['variable']."</option>"; 
   }
   echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

Now, once a selection was choosen from the first dropdown nothing happens in the second dropdown.

Thanks!

Comment: if the information is on the server and not immediately transfered client side then ajax is the way to get at it on demand. If you can bring "optional" data with the initial page load then you can store it in hidden div's. Personally i would go with the former and use ajax if there is a lot of data to be pulled for the full form, just bringing it in on demand will speed up the page load initially.

Comment: No js / JQuery at all ?

Comment: I open to suggestions using any methods. forget about no ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can use jQuery. So add a jQuery listener like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.country').on('change', function() {
        // Code to add country information in url
        location.href = location.href.split('?')[0]
            + ['?country', $(this).val()].join('=');
    });
});
</script>
```

Now on php code at the top add something like this after the code you mentioned

```
if (isset($_GET['country']) {
    $country = $_GET['country'];
    // code to prevent SQL injection
    // ... code to get data from DB using country name
    // ... code to print a new select box based on data from DB
}
```

Comment: Added the script section on top as is. and add this after my first dropdown. And add your other PHP code with this query `select variable from nhws.num_all_{$country} group by variable;` and nothing shows after choosing from the first dropdown

Comment: @user3882752 Add the php code I mentioned just after your php code.
then in the HTML content add this script, also you would have to include `jquery` library before that

Comment: I edited my question and include your code in it. it still does not work for me. Take a look at the question to see the full code. Thanks!

Comment: @user3882752 in the **PHP First dropdown**: change `<select name='country' style=width:200px>` to `<select class='country' name='country' style='width:200px'>`